# ffmpeg stream an audio file to Telegram rtmp server

Tags: ffmpeg, telegram, rtmp

I tried to stream an mp3 file to a Telegram RTMP live using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i 1.mp3 -c copy -f mp3 rtmps://dc4-1.rtmp.t.me/s/145158:AtyF3rrME2nHEkqGA
```

But I couldn't hear any sound in the stream.

Answer (score 8):

You should specify the codecs explicitly.

The following is the simplest working command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i your_input -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv rtmps://dcx-y.rtmp.t.me/s/YOUR_KEY
```

Here is a more advanced example from [@tgbeta](https://t.me/tgbeta/4555):

```sh
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i your_input -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3500k -maxrate 3500k -bufsize 7000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmps://dcx-y.rtmp.t.me/s/YOUR_KEY
```

Comment: This work but I'm having lags

Comment: That should be a problem with your connection.

Comment: I'm running it on an oracle server I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Is your input source stable?

Comment: It's a local mp4 file

Comment: Something shouldn’t be right either with your input or your connection to Telegram. You could try streaming this: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4.

Comment: https://t.me/zenakonim?livestream I'm testing it here rn

Comment: with this command ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmps://dc1-1.rtmp.t.me/s/10909994:xxxxx

Comment: Yes, or similar.

Comment: how can I reduce the quality?

Answer (score 0):

Change `-f mp3` by `-f flv`.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i 1.mp3 -c:a copy -f flv rtmps://dc4-1.rtmp.t.me/s/145158:AtyF3rrME2nHEkqGA
```

Comment: This isn’t working. The audio codec of the output must be set to `aac`.